# error when trying to share a screenshot on Android from Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

In my code, when I'm trying to press button "Take Screenshot and Share" on IoS - I'm successfully can save and share screenShot. But in android i get next error:

```
D/EGL_emulation( 6505): app_time_stats: avg=13107.49ms min=1.30ms max=380030.59ms count=29
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.swize_frontend/cache/share/customerPhotos.png
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:825)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:450)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at io.flutter.plugins.share.Share.getUrisForPaths(Share.java:128)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at io.flutter.plugins.share.Share.shareFiles(Share.java:69)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at io.flutter.plugins.share.MethodCallHandler.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandler.java:42)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/share( 6505):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
E/flutter ( 6505): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.swize_frontend/cache/share/customerPhotos.png, null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.swize_frontend/cache/share/customerPhotos.png
E/flutter ( 6505):      at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:825)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:450)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at io.flutter.plugins.share.Share.getUrisForPaths(Share.java:128)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at io.flutter.plugins.share.Share.shareFiles(Share.java:69)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at io.flutter.plugins.share.MethodCallHandler.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandler.java:42)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/flutter ( 6505):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
E/flutter ( 6505): )
E/flutter ( 6505): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
E/flutter ( 6505): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:315:18)
E/flutter ( 6505): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6505): #2      _MyAppState._takeScreenshot (package:swize_frontend/main.dart:56:5)
E/flutter ( 6505): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6505):
```

I tried adding permissions to androidManifest in main folder:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

but it didn't work for me. I'm not sure if it's a matter of permissions or maybe I specified the wrong permissions... but if the same code did not cause errors in the iPhone, then maybe it really is in them?

This is full code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
          Screenshot(
            controller: _screenshotController,
            child: Card(
                child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/images/customerPhotos.png'),
                  Text(
                    'Code Passionately',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Take Screenshot and Share'),
            onPressed: _takeScreenshot,
          )
        ]))));
  }

  void _takeScreenshot() async {
    final uint8List = await _screenshotController.capture();
    String tempPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
    File file = File('$tempPath/customerPhotos.png');
    await file.writeAsBytes(uint8List as List<int>);
    await Share.shareFiles([file.path]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The library versions are as follows:
  screenshot: ^1.3.0
  share: ^2.0.4
  path_provider: ^2.0.12

Answer (score 0):

I change lib 'share' which 'share_plus' and now sharing is working:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:file_selector/file_selector.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
          Screenshot(
            controller: _screenshotController,
            child: Card(
                child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/images/customerPhotos.png'),
                  Text(
                    'Code Passionately',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Take Screenshot and Share'),
            onPressed: _takeScreenshot,
          )
        ]))));
  }

  void _takeScreenshot() async {
    final uint8List = await _screenshotController.capture();
    String tempPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
    File file = File('$tempPath/customerPhotos.png');
    await file.writeAsBytes(uint8List as List<int>);
    final xFile = XFile(file.path);
    await Share.shareXFiles([xFile]);
  }
}
```

But now i have other problem: in android i can't choose `save into galary` option. How to add this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ywkb.png)

[image]